# Sending array with Intent to different package

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent

I have problem with an Intent for an array. I want to send an rectangular array to another package. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/how-can-i-pass-multidimensional-string-array-two-activities-t9259.html). Unfortunately, I still have a problem with the Intent. So I have the class `ActivityToSend`. I want to send `storePrintIMC` into another class (`SamplePreferenceActivity`) of a different package.

`ActivityToSend` class:

```
public class ActivityToSend extends Activity {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String[]> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public String[] inkLevels = new String[5];
    View message;
    String [][] storePrintIMC= new String [4][4];
    public static final String ARRAYS_COUNT = "com.Status.App.ARRAYS_COUNT";
    public static final String ARRAY_INDEX = "com.Status.App.ARRAY_INDEX"; 

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final String data[][] = storePrintIMC; 
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        int count = data.length; 
        bundle.putInt(ARRAYS_COUNT, count); 
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        { 
            bundle.putStringArray(ARRAY_INDEX + i, data[i]); 
        } 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SamplePreferenceActivity.class); 
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

For the second activity in the different package I use:

```
public class SamplePreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {    
    private static final int DIALOG_READ_ME = 1;
    public String[] inkLevels = new String[5];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int count = bundle.getInt(ActivityToSend.ARRAYS_COUNT, 0);

            ArrayList<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<String[]>(count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                arrays.add(bundle.getStringArray(ActivityToSmartWatch.ARRAY_INDEX + i));

            String[][] data = arrays.toArray(new String[][]{});
        }
    }
}
```

I also made some changes with the Android manifest. For the second package, I put:

```
<activity android:name=".SamplePreferenceActivity " android:label="@string/preference_activity_title">
<meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value="com.PrinterStatus.AppLab.SamplePreferenceActivity " /> 
  - <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.controlsample.SamplePreferenceActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.PrinterStatus.AppLab.ActivityToSend" /> 
<service android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.controlsample.SampleExtensionService" />
```

I get an error in the first package in:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SamplePreferenceActivity.class);
```

I don't know what I have to change. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What's the error? Did you import `SamplePreferenceActivity`?

Comment: How can I import it?is it in android manifest or in the class? when I put in class it is not possible to add it

Comment: Did you see my answer? Also (not that it makes a difference if you're getting a compiler error), do you really need the `android:parentActivityName` attribute in the manifest? You would only need it if you were starting a `SamplePreferenceActivity` from somewhere other than an `ActivityToSend` activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `SamplePreferenceActivity` is in a different package, you need to import the class into `ActivityToSend`. It's just like any other import. Judging from what's in your manifest, you need to put this near the top of `com.PrinterStatus.AppLab.ActivityToSend.java` (with the other `import` statements):

```
import com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.controlsample.SamplePreferenceActivity;
```

If you're using Eclipse, you can probably resolve the import automatically using ctrl-shift-O.

Comment: yes sir ! one up for your answer !, i misread another package as another app. sorry

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I still have problem. in class ActivityToSend the error : The constructor Bundle(ActivityToSend, Class<SamplePreferenceActivity>) is undefined.

Comment: @Carlos - I don't see that code in your original post. Why would you be trying to construct a `Bundle` like that? The arguments look like they ought to be for a new `Intent`, not a new `Bundle`.

Comment: @TedHopp- Bundle I used for intent. I refer from this site(http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/how-can-i-pass-multidimensional-string-array-two-activities-t9259.html)
Do you have any other solution?

Comment: @Carlos - There's no problem using a `Bundle` with an `Intent`. However, they have to be constructed properly. Something like this: `Bundle b = new Bundle(); /* put stuff into b, then: */ Intent intent = new Intent(this, SamplePreferenceActivity.class); intent.putExtras(b); startActivity(intent);`. Note that the `Bundle` constructor takes no arguments.