# Using Intent for Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent

I have problem with sending intent for array. Actually I have asked before this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562341/sending-array-with-intent-to-different-package). but I realized I couldn't send it to another activity. I have error when debugging it,when it comes to using intent:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) 
    {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        final String data[][] = storePrintIMC; 
        int count = data.length; 
        bundle.putInt(ARRAYS_COUNT, count); 
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        { 
            bundle.putStringArray(ARRAY_INDEX + i, data[i]); 
        } 
         Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityReceiver.class); 
         intent.putExtras(bundle);
         startActivity(intent);
```

In this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityReceiver.class);
```

It says Source not found. I have activityReceiver class, I also declare the intent in manifest.

Do you know why this is happen?

Comment: @njzk2 no he doesn't. since `data` is a 2 dimensional array

Comment: i have just edited,I was copying wrong code.

Comment: @PhilippSander : my bad, it is in fact.

Comment: @Carlos : what do you mean "It says Source not found" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.....

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityReceiver.class);
```